# Is there a cleaner, shorter version of this Google Sheets formula for determining the next date based on a recently input date?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet with the date of an initial assessment. A review for each assessment needs to be done every 90 days.

This is what the table looks like:

| Initial | Last Review | Next Review |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5/5/22 |  | 8/3/22 |

In the second column, the last review will be entered so the next review will also update. However, the review date is based on the initial assessment, not the date of the review. So if the review is done early or late, the next review date will still be based on the initial assessment.

This is what the table should look like

| Initial | Last Review | Next Review |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5/5/22 | 6/12/22 | 11/1/22 |

For now I am using this `IFS` formula in the third column that looks at the second column and updates the date for the next review:

`=IFS(B1="",A1+90,(B1>=A1+0)*(B1<=A1+90),A1+180,(B1>=A1+90)*(B1<=A1+180),A1+270,(B1>=A1+180)*(B1<=A1+270),A1+360,(B1>=A1+270)*(B1<=A1+360),A1+450,(B1>=A1+360)*(B1<=A1+450),A1+540,(B1>=A1+450)*(B1<=A1+540),A1+630)`

This works perfectly fine, but some reviews can potentially be more than 630 days later. Is there a way to shorten this formula, or will need to keep adding more and more to calculate the dates past 630 days?

Edit: So I had a realization after messing around with some of the dates and the answers provided. If the review is done late, the formula will skip a review date.

Using the example I included, if the first review is done on `8/6/22`, then the next review will be shown as `1/30/23` instead of `11/1/22`.

From the answers provided @Martin 's answer `=IF(B1="",A1+90,A1+(1+ROUNDUP((B1-A1+1)/90))*90` works perfectly if the review is done early or on time. @Arav 's answer `=IF(B1="",A1+90,B1+90-MOD(B1-A1,90))` will only work if the review is late.

Comment: what if it lands on weekend? should the formula account for it and correct the date to the nearest working day?

Comment: @player0 Weekends are fine. If the date lands on a weekend, the review is done early.

Comment: Just realized you may need an extra lapse of 90 days watching at your formula again, and added it @UmaLPZ Let me know if it's useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with ROUNDUP:

```
=IF(B1="",A1+90,A1+(1+ROUNDUP((B1-A1+1)/90))*90
```

That will calculate the amount of 90 days passed and round up to the next one 90s

### UPDATE

I think that the only case in which a date would change the calculations is when it's done early. Meaning, as you stated in your comments, 14 days before the next revision. Considering that, the formula would be with those 14 days summing:

```
=IF(B1="",A1+90,A1+(+ROUNDUP((B1-A1+14)/90))*90)
```

What should you do if the date is more than 30 days later?? If it's late, the date of the next revision shouldn't stay but keep in the next multiple of 90 days lapse. What you can do is to use some conditional formatting, for example:

```
=(MOD((B1-A1),90)>30)*(MOD((B1-A1),90)<76)
```

That considers the dates going from more than 30 days to less than 76 (because then it would be an early review of the next date)

See this conditional formatting operating in this example, in which I mapped 5 days lapse to see how the dates are changing. As you can see, the orange is for the out-of-date revisions with the previous conditional formatting; and in green I marked the places where the dates change:

[image]

Let me know!

Comment: I tried this formula. Unfortunately, it just adds one day to the next review date. If the review is done after the listed due date, it will show the next due date, but will also add another day.

Comment: There was a missing parenthesis, check again!

Comment: The answer works great if the review is done early or on time which is very helpful. I realized too late after posting the question that entering a date that is late will result in a review date being skipped.

Comment: Try changing `B1-A1+1` with the tolerance you want to have. If you want 10 days of tolerance, change 1 with `10,` or `15,` or the lapse you consider!!

Comment: The tolerance seems to go in the opposite direction. If I switch it to be `-X` instead of `+X` then it kind of works but then early reviews are not counted.

Comment: Could you please give a brief example of a couple of cases? For example if the review is meant for 15/02 from which day would be considered early and until which day it would be considered late?

Comment: It's hard to have an exact time for late reviews because the cause could be an issue outside of our control. I would say about 30 days is the latest. It also can't be too early so about 14 days before the due date would be the earliest.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you've provided is checking for specific ranges of days between the initial assessment and the last review, and then returning the next review date based on those ranges. It's a bit long and can be hard to read.

To shorten the formula and make it more flexible for future assessments, you could use the MOD function to check if the number of days between the initial assessment and the last review is a multiple of 90. If it is, the next review date would be 90 days after the last review. If not, you could add the remainder of days to 90 to get the next review date.

Here's an example of what that formula might look like:

=IF(B1="",A1+90,B1+90-MOD(B1-A1,90))

This formula checks if the last review is empty, if yes it returns the date of initial assessment plus 90 days, otherwise it returns the date of last review plus 90 days minus the remainder when last review date minus initial assessment date is divided by 90. This way, it will always give you the next review date after 90 days of the last review date, regardless of how many days past the last review date is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works great but doesn't account for the review being done early. That said, I didn't realize until just now that if the review is done late then the formula will skip a review date. Your answer is perfect for this situation! Now I have to find a way to check for both.